# Move database without creating alias

Tags: migration, sql-server, restore

when we started with Sharepoint we installed everything on a sqlserver that was used for non-sharepoint activities to. Now however we decided to seperate those from each other. Management decided that we should move all the sharepoint databases (including config) to the new SQLserver. I found an article on technet describing the whole process however one of the last steps is to create an alias on the new SQLserver. But Since we will be continuing to use the old SQLserver we won't be able to use that alias. Is there another procedure known describing how to move the databases without using aliases?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is this command: stsadm -o renameserver (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263117(v=office.12).aspx)

I still don't understand why the alias won't work for you.  When you setup an alias, it's only for that one machine, not the network/enterprise.  So you plan on having your SharePoint box talk to TWO sql servers, the old one and the new one?  If you aren't using named instances (servername\instancename) then I think the stsadm -o renameserver command should do the trick.  If do have named instances, you will either have to setup the same instance name on the new sql box or use aliases.  The renameserver command in my experience only renames the server and will not change the named instance.

Comment: beat me to it; what I would suggest is that you setup the alias on the existing SharePoint server so that is c:\windows\system32\cliconfig.exe to launch that enable TCPIP and setup your alias. Then use the command as Steve describes; stsadm -o renameserver -oldservername "OLD_SQL_INSTANCE" -newservername "ALIAS_NAME". Once you've executed this then you can move your databases to the new database server and simply update your alias accordingly.

Comment: Good call Pigeon.  I always setup my sharepoint boxes using aliases.  SPSQL01, 02, etc. depending on how many servers/instances I need.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply Steve,

we are using named instances. The old server was like SERVER\instancename. We have some databases on that server that are not being used by sharepoint at all and who need to stay there, thats the reason. I thought that by creating an alias like "SERVER\instancename" would start giving problems since the old instance is still active and reachable. But I managed to do what I wanted by creating a farm backup, closing down the farm, creating a new farm with the settings of the new sql server and performing a restore afterwards. Everything is working fine now :).

Comment: Wow, that sounds risky.  I'm glad it worked out for you.